# Corda Walking the Chain of Transactions in java

Tags: corda

In Corda:

Verifies transaction on initiator node
Notarizes transaction
Persists signedTransaction to vault of initiator
Distributes transaction to the participants
As per consensus, verification involves walking the chain.

I looked in code. Where exactly does the walking-the-chain thing happen?

Do the notary and the participants also walk the chain? If yes, they check the signatures on each transaction in the chain, but where exactly in the code does it happen?

As per my understanding, SendTransactionFlow sends the transaction to the other parties on the participants lists. The other party also requests for attachments and transaction dependencies. Where actually does the walking-the-chain thing happen?

I need to understand walking the chain from a coding perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ReceiveTransactionFlow` that responds to SendTransactionFlow.

You'll see it calls `ResolveTransactionsFlow`.
This Resolves transactions for the specified [txHashes] along with their full history (dependency graph) from the other side of the flow session i.e. walk the chain

Comment: Consider a Case where Notary is configured as Non Validating and at this time will the responder need to do the walk the chain? if YES then is he able to get all the history of transactions (all the info of all previous transactions including participants) ?